# Make a column of a GridLayout fill horizontal

Tags: java, alignment, swt, grid-layout

There is a given Formular such as the one you can see in the image.
Im am programming for a swt, RCP-App.
I can not access the components directly but have to align them using layouts.
First of all there is used a Gridlayout to align the components.
The first column holds the labels and the second one holds the  Textfields.

Whats left is, that I want the textfields to have the same width.
My original plan was to let the textfields fill the second column horizontal and then do sth. like margin-right.

There is the GridData which is capable of the following:

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false);
data.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
...
```

My code with the GridLayout looks like this:

```
GridLayout layout = new Gridlayout(2, false);

GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false);
data.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;

parent.setLayout(layout); -> Produces the given image
parent.setLayoutData(data);
-> Seems to do nothing in combination with gridlayout, but the layout is needed
```

There are way more fields with different widths but this should be enough the explain the problem.

Does anyone have an idea how to combine the layout with the griddata or has another solution. 
I want to make the textfields in the second column pretty withiut toucing them directly.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Thanks you for your help

Comment: You can add the link to the image.

Comment: Thank you, I just added the image.

Comment: Updated my answer to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The `GridData` has to be applied to the `Text`s, no their parent. So you'll have to "touch" them:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("name");
    Text name = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    name.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("memory");
    Text memory = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    memory.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("processors");
    Text processors = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    processors.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Ok, thought about your requirement again, and came up with another solution. In this solution you don't have to have a reference to the actual `Text` objects, but you'll search for them instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("name");
    new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("memory");
    new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("processors");
    new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    applyGridData(shell);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void applyGridData(Control parent)
{
    if(parent instanceof Text)
    {
        parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
    }
    else if(parent instanceof Composite)
    {
        Composite comp = (Composite) parent;

        for(Control control : comp.getChildren())
            applyGridData(control);
    }
}
```

Basically, this solution recursively searches through your `Composite` for `Text` objects and then applies the `GridData` to them.